# Web App in Eclipse using Mave

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications

I want to develop a Web App in Eclipse using Maven build tool. Where can I find a good tutorial to develop such kind of app?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your Kind Information There is no big difference between Normal And Maven application. Generally

```
1.In normal web application we add jars in lib folder in maven in pom.xml
  we add maven dependency instead of adding libs
2.The Projects structure is also changed
```